# Software Failure after RAM upgrade Amitek Hawk

Tags: hardware, amiga-1200

I have Amitek Hawk for my A1200, the board came with wrong RAM and apps were crashing with 8003 Guru error. After contacting the seller I was told by mistake wrong SIMM was shipped and I received a replacement, but this one fails to boot system, then after error continues to boot from CF, but crashes. Are the jumer settings / RAM correct?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: The jumper settings look correct to me. Is the top of C12 (located between LK2 and LK3) flat or convex (bulging)? Also try reseating all the chips, maybe use some contact cleaner on the pins and sockets to ensure a good electrical connection.

Comment: It looks like the SIMM has two TMS418169DZ chips which are 8MB each. The Hawk only supports 8MB total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely indicating a problem with the RAM added by your expansion card.

You can usually diagnose these problems better by booting with a diagnostics floppy. I would recommend trying the [Amiga Test Kit v1.4](https://github.com/keirf/Amiga-Stuff/releases).

It includes a boot floppy that runs a suite of tests, including a memory test that will probably recognize your additional RAM and can perform extensive tests. This will confirm that the RAM SIMM (vice the expansion card) is the likely culprit.

*NOTE:* As mentioned in the comments, C12 does look suspicious in your photo. If the memory test indicates intermittent problems with both SIMMs, or with a known good SIMM tested elsewhere, then recapping the expansion board may be your best bet.